# Android java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android

In some case, when accessing an activity field from an anonymous class, I get NoSuchFieldError at runtime: *java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MyActivity.myField*

**EDIT:** I'm now sure that it's an Android issue, because everything compiles correctly but resolved incorrectly at runtime. When changing to *MyActivity.this.myField* instead of plain *myField*, everything works perfect.

BTW, I rechecked and I don't have any other myField anywhere else, Also, when opening declaration in Eclipse, it goes to the intended field (*myField*).

The only problem is that I couldn't reproduce this in a sample project. I'm left only to state that it's a specific problem in my project, but I'm reluctant doing so and I can't publish this project.

I'll keep this open in case someone stumbles upon something similar.

**Here's the code that I can publish that crashes my project but not the sample one:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, myField.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Comment: Whoever votes this down, please explain the reason so I can provide a better question.

Comment: no idea ?..but please provide code..........

Comment: you have down vote(i didn't) maybe because you didn't add code for example and without code we are able to do anything.

Comment: Writing a sample code to reproduce...

Comment: I can't create a project that reproduces this. It happens only on my project. I guess it's my fault but I can't publish this project. Bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that accessing the field with the class' prefix solves it: *MyActivity.this.myField*

Strange. I guess it's something with Android's field resolution in runtime.

Comment: the weird thing is that it compiled . maybe you forcefully added casting on an anonymous class to the one of the outer class ? something like : ((MyActivity)this).myField...  ?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything like that. Also, in debug I pause on the problematic line and see that the field exists and has the expected content. This is so weird - I just can't reproduce it in a new sample project.

Comment: can you please post the relevant code? it's indeed very weird.

Comment: I can't post it all, I'll to post something.